# Where does WordPress store custom post types?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've downloaded a theme on WordPress, installed it and added a few pages etc. I'm wanting to add a bit of functionality to it so i've decided to add a sticky menu using jQuery. I've installed the relevant scripts and got the plugin working.

The theme I downloaded off themeforest allows end users to create a 'section', Which is basically a custom content type that can break parts of the page up. So on my homepage I've broken up parts of the page in to sections, but I want to add the sticky to a particular section, so when you scroll down to it, the section remains in view at all times.

To use the sticky plugin i either need to apply a class to the parent div or wrap the parent div in tags. So my question is, is there any way to actually edit the code of a custom content type? I know that WordPress works on a template basis, so every time you create a page, post etc. it's just stored in the database. But surely there must be a way to edit the code of a particular page.

I hope i've made sense. For anyone wanting to know what i'm on about heres the link -
www.gogoblondie.com

The website is still in development, but it's the black section with that i want to stick as the user scrolls.

Arran

Comment: Can we see the HTML that you need to traverse to and target to apply the `sticky`? seems as if trying to capture the output before hand and add a class is more work than necessary for this. -- *sidenote* 403 error on your link

Comment: Yeah sorry, i've only allowed access from my IP address, i'll sort that out now, 2 minutes

Comment: What's the element we need to target to apply sticky on this page?

Comment: As you can see at the moment, the sticky only applies to the yellow circle (these will have anchor tags linking to different parts of the page) but i want it to apply to the whole black section.

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.gogoblondie.com/wp-content/themes/district/js/jquery.sticky.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("nav").sticky({topSpacing:0});
 });
</script>` - that's the code i have in the footer

Comment: Then in the actual editor i just wrap the <a> tags in <nav> tags and it works...

Comment: But you want the whole `section` to have sticky? it's just `jQuery('nav').closest('.section').sticky({topSpacing:0});`

Comment: Wow, thank you that's worked - sort of. There's still some work to be done but yeah that's stuck the section to the top as you scroll, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on your markup structure and needs :

```
jQuery('nav').closest('.section').sticky({topSpacing:0});
```

Will work.